# Java dependencies

Tags: java, maven

OK I am trying to use http://jongo.org, in a project I have run `mvn install` and dropped the jar it returns into my project but when I try and use Jongo I get `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module` Does Jongo not package these directly? 
My question is do I need to then manually include the other jars it depends on aswell into my project root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need add this dependency manually in maven:

> Jongo relies upon [Jackson 2.4.1](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind), [Bson4Jackson 2.4.0](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) and [Mongo Java Driver 2.11+](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver). Its Maven dependency, an OSGI compliant jar, comes with
>   the first two, you have to provide a dependency to the driver.
>
> Jongo is deployed into OSS Sonatype (Maven repository hosting service
>   for open source projects). Add the following dependency to your
>   pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
     <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version> </dependency>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: DO I typically need the -sources.jar or the plain one?

Comment: Plain one...The `-sources.jar` can you get if you like to take a look into the source code...

Comment: but I'm still going to need the jackson.jar and the bson4jackson.jar right?

Comment: sure...that's are those artifacts which you will use and where the needed classes are packaged into...